# Regarding App ICON

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have uploaded 1 application Last week. Its currently in waiting For Review state.
In this application, I have not added the @3x (180X180) image for the App ICON.
Now when I am testing my app on iPhone 6+ the app icon appears to be black. Ideally what I think is that it should take a lower size of icon i.e. icon-120x120 @2x.png.

Do I need to reupload my app again or I should wait for the app approval?

Comment: Did you use `Image.xcassets` for icons?

Comment: Not used Image.xcassets. Used the Folder structure.

Comment: image.xcassets is good practice. Inder kumar's answer is right for u

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how your app is being submitted, you must get error while uploading to app store.

If your app icon is coming black on iPhone 6+  then apple will surely reject your app.

I would suggest you to wait for their approval as it's been a week. They might come with more issues with your app instead of just `wrong icon`. Other wise you can re-upload your app with correct icons

---

Edit:

As you mentioned you haven't used `Image.xcassets` then your app might be displayed in scale mode for iPhone 6 and 6+

Read this [article to know if your app is being run in `Scale Mode` (Get Started Section)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/89816/porting-app-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-ios-8-top-10-tips)

Comment: Actually I have uploaded this app before 1 Month with Manually release. At that time also icon is not uploaded but apple has approved the APP. In iPhone 5s and 6 icon is coming. i assume 6+ icon should be taken from 6 icon.

Comment: The icon will be taken from the iphone 5, and will run in scale mode